# Is there any trade-off between sourcing and performance?

Tags: r, performance

Does the excessive use of `source()` to use functions in multiple `.R` files come with a performance trade-off?

In other words, does the code run significantly faster when it is in a single `.R` file (that's when it's generally not very beautiful to look at) compared to when there are chunks scattered around in multiple files?

Comment: No. Sourcing a text file into the interpreter is a very low overhead operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should really ask what kinds of "gains" you stand form such a thing vs. clarity of the code
but just for completeness...

### Let's compare:

Here we source 10 fxns either in one `source()` to `long.r` or with 3 to `short1-3.r`.

#### in long.r:

```
# my long source file
fun1 <- function(x) x
fun2 <- function(x) x
fun3 <- function(x) x
fun4 <- function(x) x
fun5 <- function(x) x
fun6 <- function(x) x
fun7 <- function(x) x
fun8 <- function(x) x
fun9 <- function(x) x
fun10 <- function(x) x
```

#### in short1.r

```
# my shrt source file
fun1 <- function(x) x
fun2 <- function(x) x
fun3 <- function(x) x
```

#### in short2.r

```
fun4 <- function(x) x
fun5 <- function(x) x
fun6 <- function(x) x
```

#### in short3.r

```
fun7 <- function(x) x
fun8 <- function(x) x
fun9 <- function(x) x
fun10 <- function(x) x
```

### Benchmarking:

```
require(microbenchmark)

src_long <- function(){
source("long.r")
}

src_shorts <- function(){
    source("short1.r")
    source("short2.r")
    source("short3.r")
}


microbenchmark(src_long(),src_shorts())
```

on my machine i get:

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr        min       lq     median      uq      max     neval
  src_long()  691.690  733.271  763.3405  806.3555 3242.216   100
src_shorts() 1354.356 1431.011 1476.2555 1541.9445 3528.760   100
```

so it takes ~2x as long when you have 3 calls to `source()` instead of 1. Presumably because of the added evaluations through the `else/if` statements in source itself. **700 microseconds is not something to ride home about and thus one should defer to whatever gives clearest code**.

Comment: Better interpretation is that it takes 700 µs longer - i.e. not worth bothering about.

Comment: @hadley very much agreed, hence the disclaimer at the top of my answer. have edited to "enforce" the point of view at the bottom as well.